# Single quotes, Double quotes as Python input values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the following command and I got different values stored in the variable each time.

```
name=input('enter your name:')
enter your name:'' (two single quotes)
name
"''" (this is how it is displayed after I type 'Name' and press 'Enter')

name=input('enter your name:')
enter your name:"" (two double quotes)
name
'""' (this is how it is displayed after I type 'Name' and press 'Enter')

name=input('enter your name:')
enter your name:"'"' (double, single, double, single)
name
'"\'"\'' (this is how it is displayed after I type 'Name' and press 'Enter')

name=input('enter your name:')
enter your name:'"'" (single, double, single, double)
name
'\'"\'"' (this is how it is displayed after I type 'Name' and press 'Enter')
```

What does the \ indicate in the variable 'name' and why is it at all there?

Comment: if you have `"` in a string its displayed between `'` as delimeters. The same the other way round. If you have both in your string, they are prefixed by \ to display that they do not end the string but are part of it. its called _escaping_. same for \r\n (carr-return,linefeed), \t (tab) etc.

Comment: you could use `""" a multiline string can hold " and ' unescaped """` - but python doesn't by itself.

Comment: Surprised that people have down-voted my question. I am just a beginner, so is it a crime to ask 'basic' questions on Stackoverflow? I did search Google before asking this, and couldn't find a satisfactory answer and hence asked it here.

Comment: Downvotes do not citicize you - they are feedback from the community that your questions lacks ... _something_ ... you can ask anything, if the community thinks it shows not enough research effort or is a bad fit for [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you get voted down. However if you add what you researched and format it nicely and are responsive for comments asking for clarification you get upvotet. Thats SO in a nutshell...

Answer (score 1):

It is there to escape a single quote in a single quotes strings. This "escaping" allows you to use single and/or double quotes in a string. You can work around this by using a double quote in a string quoted with single quotes are vice versa. But this does not work anymore if you have a string with single quotes and double quotes. So you have use escaping now.

The Python console just wants you to see the variable, not the contents of the variable that's why you see escaping. You can also just display the string with print and you won't see the escaping, because you now just see the string as is.

So, just use `print(name)`

Comment: In particular, what is displayed in the console is the `repr` of the output. The representaion is meant to be what would return the same object when evaluated, it thus needs escaping